# Assigning a variable within a while loop in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ksh

I am trying to assign a variable within a while loop and the script hangs during the read statement.

```
while read -r port  60720 60721 60722 60723 60724
```

here is the code:

```
 qmgrs=$($MQ_INSTALL_PATH/bin/dspmq | grep QMNAME | awk -F\( '{ print $2}'| awk -F\) '{ print $1}')

numqmgrs=$($MQ_INSTALL_PATH/bin/dspmq | grep QMNAME | wc -l)

strqmgrs=(${qmgrs})

i=$numqmgrs
arrayindex=0

while ((i != 0))
do
while read -r port  60720 60721 60722 60723 60724 ;do

  qmgrname=${strqmgrs[$arrayindex]}


echo "

this is the $port for the $qmgrname”


i=$((i-1))
  arrayindex=$((arrayindex+1))
done
done
```

desired output:

```
this is the 60720 for the apple”
this is the 60721 for the pear”
this is the 60722 for the mango”
this is the 60723 for the grape”
this is the 60724 for the blueberry”
```

Comment: What `ksh` are you using? `ksh93`?

Comment: Is that `while read -r port  60720 60721 60722 60723 60724` supposed to be `for port in 60720 60721 60722 60723 60724`?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes thats right ksh93

Comment: @roaima you are right. script hangs. for loop didnt work either. Its not setting the port value using for as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you'd like to pair a static list of port numbers with server names that you get from a command.

Do this instead:

```
PATH=$MQ_INSTALL_PATH/bin:$PATH

ports=( 60720 60721 60722 60723 60724 )
i=0

dspmq | sed -n '/QMNAME/{ s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p; }' |
while read -r server && [ "$i" -lt "${#ports[@]}" ]; do
    printf 'Port on %s is %d\n' "$server" "${ports[i]}"
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

This is essentially what you were trying to do, but you used two nested loops rather than a single loop with a combined condition.  The code is also reading the server names directly from the command pipeline that produces these without storing them in an intermediate array.

If you want to hand out the port numbers in the opposite order, use

```
PATH=$MQ_INSTALL_PATH/bin:$PATH

ports=( 60720 60721 60722 60723 60724 )
i=${#ports[@]}

dspmq | sed -n '/QMNAME/{ s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p; }' |
while read -r server && [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; do
    i=$(( i-1 ))
    printf 'Port on %s is %d\n' "$server" "${ports[i]}"
done
```

The `${#ports[@]}` expression will in all cases above expand to the number of elements in the `ports` array.

The `sed` command

```
sed -n '/QMNAME/{ s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p; }'
```

will extract the string within the first parenthesis on the lines that contain the string `QMNAME`.  It could also be written

```
sed -n '/QMNAME/{ s/.*(//; s/).*//p; }'
```

Comment: port list is static, but not the server list. I comverted to static list for sake of simplicity..Thats the reason to use the numqmgrs as a counter to end the loop when the count is 0.

Comment: @MO12 Hmm... You will have to update your question with some actual code to show the problem. We could possibly help you get that current code working, but it would be assuming a _static_ list of servers.  If that is not what you have, then the corrected code will still be wrong for you.  Are you, for example reading the server names from a file?

Comment: updated my question. I am deriving the qmgrname and numqmgr from output of another command

Comment: @MO12 See update answer.

Comment: @MO12 The `$server` value in the `while` loop is being `read` from the `sed` command on the line previous. Note the `|` at the end of the `sed` command  that pipes it into the loop.

Comment: @MO12 Well, you are using the part of my answer that goes through the ports in reverse order, so that is what I'd expert it to do.

Comment: Thanks again.That worked.